# How to inflate a recycleview inside an adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, instagram, android-adapter

So basically [here is the setup I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQa2b.png) and [this is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw0Fd.jpg). I currently have 2 adapters merged into 1 mergeAdapter to get the functionality of stories being the "header" of the app. Now the problem is they are all together inside a recycleview that's vertical. I need the first adapter to be inside the mergeAdapter but have a horizontal layout. I've asked around and it seems that I have to inflate the recycle view inside my header adapter and then use that as the layout, but I have no clear idea how to achieve this.

This is the response that I got:

"Technically it really is in theory "as simple as" inflating a layout that contains a RecyclerView as an item, and setting it up as an item view type. and getting the list to show into that item.

You really just need to create 2 adapters (if you go the MergeAdapter route), where one displays 1 item of a horizontal recycler view, and the other displays n items of the vertical list. Then put the two adapters in a MergeAdapter, now you don't even need to worry about item view types. That's what's thrown people off for almost a decade."

Edit: 
To clarify, I have no idea how can adapters inflate anything other than view holders. And how can I inflate a recycle view and then use attach views to it, where do I even create it, how do I hold a reference to it in the adapter? I understand the concept behind it but I couldn't' find any examples that utilize this online so I've had no luck. Basically, if anyone can just describe the thought process behind it but a little bit more concrete, I cannot wrap my head around it atm.

Eg. You'd inflate the recycle view with `inflater.inflate(R.id.recycleview)` inside the init of the adapter and then store it in a variable to use in bindviewholder...

Comment: The response you got is the correct answer. You're going to need to explain what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Added an edit to hopefully clarify it a bit, basically, I understand the idea but have no idea where and how to implement it properly. Hopefully, someone knows a project or something that implements this design.

Comment: Remember how you can create a `layout` file like `my_view.xml` that has a `<FrameLayout` at its root and has some views on it? Now put a `<RecyclerView` at its root instead and pass it into your ViewHolder like in any Adapter's `onCreateViewHolder` method.